# Printing a particular String according to boolean value in Java

Tags: java, tostring

I m defining a Shape class with constructors, get and set methods, toString methods etc... And in toString method, I have to print **" is Filled "** or **" is not Filled "** according to a **given boolean value.**

I also wrote a getter method for boolean type such as:

```
    ...
    ...
    private boolean filled;
    ...
    ...

    //Constructor 
    public Shape(boolean f){
        filled = f;
    }
    ...

    // Getter Method for Boolean values
    public boolean isFilled(){
        return filled;
    }
```

But I have no idea how to write a proper toString method which prints out **"is filled "** or **" is not filled "** according to a given value of **" boolean filled "**

any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: well, I did not born as a java master :P ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to achieve what you want

### Solution

```
boolean filled;
// code
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "blabla " + (filled? "filled" : "not filled") + " other blabla";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works very well. Actually I feel guilty a little, I see how easy it is...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following:

```
public String toString()
{
    if(isFilled())
    {
        return "is filled";
    }
    else
    {
        return "is not filled ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
public String toString() {
    return filled ? "is filled" : "is not filled";
}
```